# ModelMultipleChoiceField returns "name Object"

Tags: html, django

I have a problem using ModelMultipleChoiceField. I have a Model named Instrumentation and other named InstTemplate:

```
class Instrumentation(models.Model):
    code        = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    marca       = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    modelo      = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    familia     = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    subfamilia  = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    calibration_date    = models.DateField()
    #test       = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    notes       = models.TextField(max_length=170, blank=True)
    utilization = models.DateField(blank=True)


    def is_free(self):
        return (self.utilization == None)

    def is_calibrated(self):
        return (self.calibration_date > date.today())



class InstTemplate(models.Model):

    name        = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    equipo      = models.ManyToManyField(Instrumentation)
    boards      = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    project     = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    notes       = models.TextField(max_length=170, blank=True)
```

I would like to implement a multiple select with checkboxes in field "equipo" which is a ManyToManyField. This multiple selection, as I have read, is implemented in forms.py:

```
class InstTemplateForm(forms.ModelForm):

        BOARD_CHOICES = (('1','ML801/AP815'),('2','ML455/AP455'),('3','ML801/AP801'),('4','ML801/AP836i'), ('5','ML801/AP809'), ('6','CANHEAD'), ('7','ML74/AP74'),('8','ML74/AP75'))
        boards = forms.MultipleChoiceField(BOARD_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

        equipo = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), queryset=Instrumentation.objects.all())

        class Meta:
            model = InstTemplate
```

But in HTML, with the following code, I only get the database "id" field and the name "Instrumentation object" for all the objects that the queryset gets. Therefore, the queryset is working, but I only get "Instrumentation object".

```
{% block page %}
<div id="form" class="tab-content clearfix" style="display: block;">
    <h4><strong>New instrumentation template: project {{ project.ref }}</strong></h4>
    <hr class="alt1"/>
    <form class="vertical" action="{% url "new_instrumentation" project.ref %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.as_ul }}

    </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

[image]

How can I get the fields of the Instrumentation object??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define [`__unicode__`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.__unicode__) method in `Instrumentation` model for human-readable representation of the model object:

```
class Instrumentation(models.Model):
    code        = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True)
    marca       = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    modelo      = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    familia     = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    subfamilia  = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    calibration_date    = models.DateField()
    #test       = models.ForeignKey(Test)
    notes       = models.TextField(max_length=170, blank=True)
    utilization = models.DateField(blank=True)


    def is_free(self):
        return (self.utilization == None)

    def is_calibrated(self):
        return (self.calibration_date > date.today())

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.code # or self.marca what ever you want
```

Comment: Obligatory Python 3 note: in Python 3, the method to define is `__str__`, rather than `__unicode__`.